# Unix command to find user holding a process

Tags: unix

In unix, what command exists to know which user (login id) is holding a particular PID. I need to kill the process but dont have rights. So need to track down the user who started the process and ask him/her to kill it

Comment: shouldn't this go to superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com instead of stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps aux` will show all running processes with their owner. 
You can then grep for the PID if you know it.

Alternatively you can do `ps u -p <PID>` the USER will be displayed as first column.

Answer (score 0):

`awk '{print $1, $2, $11}' <(ps aux)` will output a set of columns of the form `USER PID PID PROGRAM` you can then pipe this into a `grep` for the process you want. All together looking for an xterm instance this would look like `awk '{print $1, $2, $11}' <(ps aux) | grep xterm` and it's output might resemble

```
user1 24095 xterm
user2 27420 xterm
```